# jQuery - Run jQuery script each time a “.load” function is called?

Tags: jquery

I know this is a duplicate question, but i can't fix my problem with existing answers.

my main script

```
$("a.load_item").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    $('.page_title').html(title);
    $("#content .jspPane").html('<span class="loading"></span>');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#content .jspPane").load(content, function() {
            api.reinitialise();
            $('#content .select select').customSelect();
        });
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

inside content script

```
$('.plus').live("click", function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).parents('td').find(".productQty").val();
    var stockValue = $(this).parents('td').find(".stockRemain").val();
    if (stockValue > 0) {
        currentValue++;
        $(this).parents('td').find('.productQty').val(currentValue);
    }
    calculate();
});
```

input.productQty value = 1

first time increment 2,3,4...

second time increment 3,5,7...

third time increment 4,8,12...

what is the problem ? how can i fix this? please help me.

Comment: yes indeed, what is the problem?!

Comment: Probably not a good idea to start off with `I know this is a duplicate question`

Comment: What are `api.reinitialise()` and `.customSelect()` doing?

Comment: .customSelect() is a custom select box function. that function included in main script file. api.reinitialise() jScrollPane reload content

Comment: You appear to be binding a live event over and over and over and over. You only need to bind those once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for certain what `api.reinitialise()` does, or what the problem exactly is, but for what i've understood, are you trying to execute `api.reinitialize()` everytime there's a ' `.load()`?

If so you should look at http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/ to get something like:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  api.reinitialise();
});
```